# Why does Xcode always say, "xxx is already running. Click stop to terminate and launch new instance“?

Tags: xcode

Once I've run my project, I can't run it again.

I also can't quit Xcode; when I try, it stops responding.

Does anyone know the source of this problem?  It's been happening for two days.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because there's not enough information here to even make an educated guess.  Some general troubleshooting steps are: reinstall Xcode, remove plugins, reset your simulator, and make sure you didn't modify the Xcode bundle.  You could also check your console log or crash report for more clues.

Comment: What version of XCode are you using and what version of iOS are you targeting?

Comment: i reinstalled.it's ok now.

Comment: I think I got the reason.Even i reinstalled xcode,i can't run mac app project.It says:connection refused.Yesterday I had modified the /etc/hosts and change 127.0.0.1 localhost to realip localhost.And the realip had changed,maybe this is the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check these things

- Restart PC and try again.
- Check your process list, for anything related to xcode

If non of these work, I'm stumped xD

Comment: reinstalled xcode.now it's ok now.